# resulting from or resulted from?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

Which one of these sentences is correct?

For an academic paper

The third theme resulting from focus group interviews was cultural barriers.

The third theme resulted from focus group interviews was cultural barriers.

what about these phrases?

Table 4.1 Themes resulted from the interviews of step 1

Table 4.1 Themes resulting from the interviews of step 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though you mean that there was no set program for these interviews, but certain topics appeared in many of them .

*resulted from* is just not correct at all in this context. *resulting from* is getting warmer, but it still isn't the right wording.  Maybe even no more than "Themes from the interviews of step 1..." is enough, but that might be taken to mean that the interviewer decided in advance on a set of topics for discussion (which doesn't seem to be what you mean). So I'd consider wordings like

*Themes emerging from the interviews...* or
*Themes frequently coming up in the interviews...*

The last is somewhat informal and may not be appropriate for academic work.